# atof, structs and pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, tree, atof

This is a sample of code that I've written for a school science fair.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

struct FUNC{
    char token;
    FUNC *left;
    FUNC *right;
};

double eval (FUNC *head){
    if (head->left==NULL){ 
        return atof(head->token); //this is where the error occurs
    }
}

void main(){
    FUNC node1= {'1',NULL,NULL};

    cout << eval(&node1)<< endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

When I run this code I receive this error.

```
error C2664: 'atof' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'const char *'
```

Can anyone explain this error and give me an example on how to remedy it?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. You are passing a char to a function that expects a char*.

```
struct FUNC{
    char token;
    FUNC *left;
    FUNC *right;
};
```

should be

```
struct FUNC{
    char* token;
    FUNC *left;
    FUNC *right;
};
```

and while you are at it you also would have to initialize the char* so you would have to make a function like

```
   FUNC* initFunc(const char* str,FUNC* left,FUNC* right)
   {
       // (FUNC*) is a cast to a type of pointer to FUNC. It is not needed if you write in C but 
       //since I saw cout in your code then if it's C++ you need to cast the results of malloc
       FUNC* ret = (FUNC*) malloc(sizeof(FUNC);
       int len = strlen(str);
       ret->str = malloc(len+1);
       strcpy(ret->str,str);
       ret->left = left;
       ret->right = right;
       return ret;
   }
```

So finally in your main you would have something like this:

```
//please note the existence of " " since this is not a char but a string literal
FUNC* node1 = initFunc("1",NULL,NULL);

cout << eval(node1)<< endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of advise, you should include the header cmath in place of math.h. Quoting [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/migrating_to_namespaces.htm)

> > ""Namespace Rule #3: Use C headers with the new style "`#include <cheader>`"
> >     instead of the old style "`#include <header.h>`".
> >
> > For backward compatibility with C, C++ still supports all of the standard C header names 
> >     (e.g., stdio.h), and when you #include those original versions the associated C library functions are visible in the global namespace as before--but in the same breath C++ also says that the old header names are deprecated, which puts the world on notice that they may be removed in a future version of the C++ standard. Thus Standard C++ strongly encourages programmers to prefer using the new versions of the C headers that start with "c" and drop the ".h" extension (e.g., cstdio); when you #include the C headers using the new names, you get the same C library functions, but now they live in namespace std."
> >     "

Comment: Thanks, I'm working off an old text book and they said math.h

Answer (score 0):

To get the numeric value of a single character, just use:

```
c - '0'
```

Not sure why you were going to use `atof` anyway, for a number that isn't fractional.  The function of choice for parsing strings into whole numbers should usually be `strtod`, but as mentioned, with one character you don't need even that.

Comment: The eval function isn't complete because I was stuck.
But I need the value as a double because you can't divide an int value.

The FUNC structure is an operator tree so I need the char type there  because the tree needs to contain chars like '/' for division

Comment: @WilliamInasuitBolduc: You can `return head->token - '0';` and the compiler will automatically convert to the return type, double.